# Smash product and the integers in a Grothendieck $(\infty, 1)$-topos

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, terminology, topos-theory

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Grothendieck $(\infty,1)$-topos. According to [this page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/suspension+object) in nlab, for any $X \in \mathcal{H}$, the suspension object $\Sigma X$ is homotopy equivalent to the smash product $B \mathbb{Z} \wedge X$, where $B \mathbb{Z}$ is the "classifying space of the discrete group of integers." Furthermore, for any pointed object $X \in \mathcal{H}_*$ and any group object $G \in Grp(\mathcal{H})$, the article says we can "form the tensor product $X \otimes G \in Grp(\mathcal{H})$."

My problem is: none of this terminology is explained, nor does the page provide a reference. Specifically, what is $\mathbb{Z}$ in an arbitrary $\infty$-topos? What is the smash product $\wedge$? What is the tensor product $\otimes$? My best guess is that $\otimes$ refers to the unique tensor structure on $\mathcal{H}_*$ such that the map $\mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}_*$ is symmetric monoidal (here $\mathcal{H}$ is given the Cartesian monoidal structure), but this is only a guess.

Is there a reference where all these notions are defined?

Comment: I think that $\mathbb{Z}$ in an $(\infty,1)$-topos is the constant sheaf associated to the ordinary $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The object $X$ in your first paragraph should be pointed, I think. Then as $\mathbf{B}\mathbb{Z}$ is also pointed, I would imagine that the smash product is defined in the usual way as a homotopy quotient of the product by the wedge sum, which is itself a homotopy pushout.

Comment: So we pick an identification of our topos with a category of sheaves on some site and take the sheafification of the constant presheaf corresponding to the integers? Also, how does one prove that the topos is tensored over its category of group objects?

Comment: Every $(\infty,1)$-topos has an nno, by applying the inverse image part of the canonical geometric morphism to Spaces, and inverse image functors preserve the relevant structure to build the integers from the natural numbers. Which is pretty much what you said, but in a model-independent way :-). Or else, form the circle as a homotopy pushout of the 'usual diagram' of finite sets' and take its loop space. This will give the integers, too, much like in HoTT, but now the object is a bit fatter, and not a strict group object.

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head how the $(\infty,1)$-category of pointed objects in a topos is tensored over $\infty$-groups, sorry.

Comment: Ah it's always nice to have a model independent argument. At least in an $\infty$-topos, doesn't "group object" essentially mean just "group up to coherent homotopy" (hence closure under taking deloopings)?

Comment: Yes, I suppose in a model-independent setting one cannot say that the integers form a strict group object. If one is given a higher topos as a topos of sheaves, then one might as well use the strict model. Otherwise, the loop space of the circle is the canonical object.

Comment: @DavidRoberts You can totally say model-independently what a strict group object is: it is an algebra for the Lawvere theory of (strict) groups (if you want, the homotopy category of the Lawvere theory of "nonstrict" groups). It's fairly straightforward to see that left-exact functors preserve algebras for Lawvere theories and so $\mathbb{Z}$ is a strict group object in every topos.

Comment: @DenisNardin ah, good to know! I think I was working in "maximally invariant" mode (something like Makkai's super non-strict vision of mathematics) where by default nothing is an equality.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Sure me too, but you can still define 0-truncation, right? :) Then the Lawvere theory is (the opposite) of the subcategory of all groups in spaces spanned by the 0-truncations of free groups on finite sets (to define finite sets, take the full subcategory of spaces generated under binary coproducts by the terminal objects...)

Comment: @Denis sure, though in HoTT, a 0-truncated object merely has contractible components :-) The loop space of the circle is 0-truncated in that way.

Comment: @DenisNardin: In my understanding, by “strict groups” people usually really mean strict with respect to the on-the-nose equality of some model, which isn’t and can’t be a model-invariant notion.  What you’re describing is what I’d see as the model-invariant/homotopy-invariant replacement of the concept — which I agree is the better thing to think of, in general, but I don’t think it’s quite what people (at least people I know/read) would usually mean by “strict groups”.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Ofc it depends on where you are using it, but the ∞-category I described is what you obtain when you take topological groups and invert weak equivalences, and the latter model category is what people usually mean when they say "strict groups" (it is, ofc, more relevant for abelian groups). But YMMV.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Speaking of strict groups without context, I agree I’d understand that — but speaking of strict groups *in* a general $(\infty,1)$-topos (as we were), I would understand it to be the general non-model-invariant notion.  But I guess we’ve split this hair far enough, I’ll stop wrangling over it now :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize the comments so far:

- In an arbitrary $(\infty,1)$-topos $\mathcal{E}$, the integers can be defined as the loop space of the circle $S^1_\mathcal{E}$, which itself is given as the (homotopy) pushout of two copies of the map $\mathrm{pt}\sqcup \mathrm{pt} \to \mathrm{pt}$ in $\mathcal{E}$. Otherwise, one can calculate them as the image of the usual $\mathbb{Z}$ under the inverse image $\mathcal{S}paces \to \mathcal{E}$ of the canonical map to $\mathcal{S}paces$. Note that in this definition, $\mathbf{B}\mathbb{Z}$ *is* $S^1_\mathcal{E}$, and has a canonical (up to equivalence) basepoint.
- The smash product of a pointed object $X$ in $\mathcal{E}$ and $S^1_\mathcal{E}$ is defined as the (homotopy) coequaliser of the two canonical maps
  $$
  X \vee S^1_\mathcal{E} \mathrel{\mathop{\rightrightarrows}^{\mathrm{pt}}_{\mathrm{incl.}}} X\times S^1_\mathcal{E}
  $$
  where the wedge sum $X \vee S^1_\mathcal{E}$ is the (homotopy) pushout of $X\leftarrow \mathrm{pt} \to S^1_\mathcal{E}$.

Comment: I do have one more question. Is it easy to see that a left adjoint $F: \mathcal{H}_* \to Grp(\mathcal{H})$ to the functor $ \Omega B: Grp(\mathcal{H}) \to \mathcal{H}_*$ should always exist? One would have to show at least that $\Omega B$ preserves limits, but if $Grp(\mathcal{H})$ is not presentable I don't see why this would be enough

Comment: @leibnewtz Well, $Grp(\mathcal{C})$ is always presentable if $\mathcal{C}$ is presentable (since it is a Bousfield localization of the presentable category $\mathrm{Fun}(\mathrm{Fin}_*,\mathcal{C})$)

Comment: Isn't it easier to just say that $\mathbb{Z}_{\mathcal{E}}$ is the coproduct of $\mathbb{Z}$-many copies of the terminal object?  I would expect $\Omega S^1 \simeq \mathbb{Z}$ to be a theorem, not a definition...

Comment: @Mike sure, that occurred to me, too, but if one is being picky about minimal machinery to construct the integers, using finite (co)limits might be cleaner. But then, I suppose, one does want to know how $\Omega S^1_\mathcal{E}$ relates to $\Delta \Omega S^1 \simeq \Delta \mathbb{Z}$, but surely they are equivalent by the exactness and cocontinuity of $\Delta$, and the construction of $\Omega S^1$?

Comment: @DavidRoberts Yeah, since $\Delta$ is left exact you just need to verify it for the topos of spaces. There it is a theorem, ofc, that $S^1$ is 1-truncated with $\pi_1$ given by $\mathbb{Z}$. I don't know if there's any proof using only HoTT machinery.

Comment: @DenisNardin I'm not sure if pure HoTT knows about $\Gamma: \mathcal{E} \leftrightarrows \mathcal{S}paces :\Delta$, or can internally "know" that one is talking about the terminal $(\infty,1)$-topos, but that's an interesting different question.

Comment: @DenisNardin $\Omega S^1=\mathbb{Z}$ was the very first synthetic homotopy theory proven in HoTT! (https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3443)  True, that "$\mathbb{Z}$" is slightly different from the one in the image of $\Delta$ (which "pure HoTT" indeed does not know about), but their equivalence is much more straightforward (nothing about descent or homotopy theory).  (Modal HoTT can "know about" a geometric morphism, and prove that the inverse image functor preserves $\mathbb{Z}$.)